# Codeigniter windows server web.config - how to escape .jpg or images files from url

Tags: image, codeigniter, web-config

I have a `codeigniter` website in a Windows server and it seems to be working well after I used the web.config file. But the the problem is that i cannot pass .jpg files in the url. There is a function to delete image in my admin section as follows;

```
site.com/admin/news/delete_file/image/23b90-gallery.jpg?_=1451204170539
```

Which returns me a **404** not found error.

If I remove '|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|' from the pattern {REQUEST_FILENAME} of web.config , the delete function work, but no images are displayed in the website at all.

```
 <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                    <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|eot|woff|ttf|svg|txt|pdf|swf)$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
```

is there a workaround for this. Many thanks for checking it.

Comment: Have you tried doing this through the CI routes.php file? `$route['admin/news/delete_file/(:any)'] = "path_to_controller";` and then accessing the file to be deleted with `$this->uri->segment(4); or is your issue that you are getting a redirect to your index because of your web.config?

Comment: @LionelRitchietheManatee, That's an idea worth trying. Thanks for the tip. I'll update the status after trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a matchType="IsFile" to `<conditions>` solved the issue.
So the rule will become

```
<rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|eot|woff|ttf|svg|txt|pdf|swf)$"  matchType="IsFile"  negate="true" />

                     </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```